# how to produce the postgresql date output in php?

Tags: php

How to produce this kind of date string in PHP ?
this sample date string below is coming from a postgresql output

```
2020-10-20 14:44:37.060966+08
```

I already tried something like

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:sO',strtotime('now'));
```

and

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:sOT',strtotime('now'));
```

but still i cannot produce the part starting from the decimal point to the end of my sample string.. so how to generate that format with decimal and + something something right after the seconds in PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That part is microsecond, you can use this format `Y-m-d H:i:s.uO` to add microsecond.

One thing to note that microsecond format with date() will always be `000000`. Use [DateTime::format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.uO');
```

Output:

```
2020-12-07 03:17:37.011493+0100
```